# A problem on Principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, intuition, inclusion-exclusion

[image]

I am having a little bit of trouble understanding this part in my book. I know the normal PIE that is n(A+B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(AB) and then so on for more sets but I am not able to understand this form.  What do they mean by numerical value associated is constant, what is meant by N(i) common value?

So could someone please explain this to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are inventing notation to simplify things... *in the case that* $n(a_1a_2)=n(a_1a_3)=n(a_1a_4)=\dots=n(a_2a_3)=\dots=n(a_ia_j)$ for all $i<j$ then rather than writing $n(a_1a_2)$ they write $N(2)$.  Similarly, *in the case that* $n(a_1a_2a_3)=n(a_1a_2a_4)=\dots=n(a_ia_ja_k)$ for all $i<j<k$ then instead of writing $n(a_1a_2a_3)$ they just write $N(3)$ and so on for larger tuples.

Reworded, they are saying that in the event that all pairs have the same size as each other, all triples have the same size as each other, etc... then:

$|a_1\cup a_2\cup \dots \cup a_n|=n\cdot |a_1|-\binom{n}{2}\cdot |a_1\cap a_2| + \binom{n}{3}\cdot |a_1\cap a_2\cap a_3|-\dots + (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n}{k}|a_1\cap a_2\cap \cdots \cap a_k|+\dots$

They just wanted to shorten the notation, rather than saying "The size of the intersection of the $k$ sets $|a_1\cap a_2\cap \dots \cap a_k|$" they instead just say "The size of the intersection of $k$ sets $N(k)$."

Comment: oh wow. i did not realise they were saying *in case* all have same size, so i was very confused. Thank you so much for this

Comment: @Aditya_math quite.  An example problem where this comes into play would be "*Find the number of length $10$ strings over the characterset $\{a,b,c,d\}$ such that every character occurs at least once each*" which you will find is $4^{10}-4\cdot 3^{10}+6\cdot 2^{10}-4\cdot 1^{10}+1\cdot 0^{10}$

Comment: why is this not just the number of ways of writing 10 as sum of 4 positive integers which is $\binom{9}{6}$ . Or maybe i am not understanding the meaning of length 10 strings

Comment: @Aditya_math because order within a string matters.  The string `aaaaabbbcd` is different than the string `bbbcaaaaad`.  [String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)).  It is another way of saying "sequence."  One string is considered different than another iff they are of different lengths or there is a position in the strings where the character appearing in that position in the first string is different than the corresponding character in the same position in the second string.

Comment: oh so for the question, n(required) = n(total) - n(A u B u C u D) where A is the set in which a does not appear and so on, and then as in this case, all {A,B,C,D and A intersect B and so on} have same cardinality, we would use the above formula for n(A u B u C u D). Thanks, this makes it much clearer!